# Angular JS and Ionic filter query

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, ionic-framework, angular-filters

I am trying to add a search filter to my Angular/Ionic app this is for a search box, but the data in the list is from a Wordpress api and is for the localStorage the code is:

```
<li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat='tag in item.tags track by $index'>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="option.city[$index]">
     </label>
     <p ng-bind-html="tag.title"></p>
</li>
```

How do you apply the filter in the ng-repeat directive?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you right..

Just add a filter expression in your ng-repeat... "yourSearchTextField" would be the ng-model of the search input text field

```
<li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat='tag in item.tags track by $index | filter:yourSearchTextField'>
```

Comment: Could you post the html code of your searchTextInput? Is it in the same scope as your ng-repeat?

Comment: <div class="item item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
    </label>
    <button class="button ion-close-circled input-button button-small"
              ng-click="search = ''">
              Clear search
            </button>

  </div>

Comment: its in the same scope